# How to dynamically add query clauses while using Rally Api

Tags: c#

I am using Rally Api to fetch some details, need to add more query clauses(.and) dynamically. Tried creating a string and then adding but parse error is what I am getting. Can some one help here?

## editing

storyRequest.Query = new Query("LastUpdateDate", Query.Operator.GreaterThan, "2013-08-01");

Supposing I want to keep adding .and queries to the above one dynamically based on my inputs.
For instance I want the stories for different projects, iterations and releases and the user selects them.so in that case how will I add. I tried creating a string which will have and queries based on the input but am unable to append it to the earlier one. Any approach here would be useful.

Comment: Please share your code. Without seeing code we can only guess the issue and suggest the solution in the air.

Comment: Please provide the error, along with the code, and anything else which might be relevant to the issue. Technically, you should be able to add anything you want (as the query is simply a string) before you call the Rally/REST api. Parse errors generally come with a little more information, so you get an idea of where the parser failed.

Comment: After my edit in the post, any help here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you are looking for solution like this. Dont have enough reputation to comment. this is an example in java

```
    //Inside Function start
public static QueryFilter q;
private static QueryFilter setDynamicQuery(String fieldName,String Operator,String fieldValue)
{
q=new QueryFilter(fieldName, Operator, fieldValue);
return q;
}
//Inside Function end

//When calling in main method start
QueryRequest existUserStoryRequest = new QueryRequest("HierarchicalRequirement");
String existStoryFormattedIDLst="US23456!US23457!US23446";
for(String StoryFormattedID:existStoryFormattedIDLst.split("!")){
existUserStoryRequest.setQueryFilter(setDynamicQuery("FormattedID", "=", StoryFormattedID));

}
//When calling in main method end
```